# Is every subspace of a normed linear space which is not closed a hyperspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $B \subset X$ where $X$ is a normed linear space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is a proper subspace. If $B$ is not closed, is $B$ necessarily a hyperspace(maximal proper subspace) in $X$. 
I attempted to prove this.

Attempted proof:

Choose a basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of $B$ and extend it to a basis $\mathfrak{X}$ of $X$.

Let $f \colon \mathfrak{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map which is $0$ on $\mathfrak{B}$ and $1$ on $\mathfrak{X} \setminus \mathfrak{B}$

$   
f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{0} &\quad\text{if x $\in \mathfrak{B}$}\\
       \text{1} &\quad\text{otherwise}\\
       \end{cases}$

This map being defined on basis extend linearly to the whole space.

By 1-1 correspondence of submodules, the kernel of above map is a hyperspace. Hence $B$ is a hyperspace.

What is wrong here?

Comment: let $x_1$ and $x_2\in \mathfrak {X\setminus B}$. Then $x_1-x_2\notin B$ but clearly $f(x_1-x_2)=1-1=0$... so the kernel of your map may be bigger than $B$.

Where are you using that your subspaces is not closed?

Comment: It's not true. Let $X$ be $\ell_2$ and $B$ be the set of vectors with first coordinate zero and only finitely many non-zero coordinates.